# inheriting property from parent-class

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, properties

I thought this was 100% straight-forward and am feeling more than a bit dumb<s>founded</s> right now. I have an `NSObject` based class `NORPlayer` with a public property:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pointRollers;`

This is however not inherited by the sub-class.
The array is set up like this, and it works just fine:

**PARENT-CLASS:**

```
@implementation NORPlayer

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setup{
    NSMutableArray *tempRollersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
        NORPointRoller *aRoller = [[NORPointRoller alloc] init];
        [tempRollersArray addObject:aRoller];
    }
    _pointRollers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempRollersArray];
}
```

When trying to create a subclass from `NORPlayer` to `NORVirtualPlayer` however something goes awry:

**SUB-CLASS:**

```
#import "NORPlayer.h"

@interface NORVirtualPlayer : NORPlayer

// none of the below properties nor the method pertains to the problem at hand
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray *minimumAcceptedValuePerRound;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger scoreGoal;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger acceptedValueAdditionWhenScoreGoalReached;

- (void)performMoves;

@end
```

The initialization of `NORVirtualPlayer` is mirroring its parent-class with the init method calling a setup method:

```
@implementation NORVirtualPlayer

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setup{
    self.minimumAcceptedValuePerRound = @[ @5, @5, @5, @5, @5 ];
    self.scoreGoal = 25;
    self.acceptedValueAdditionWhenScoreGoalReached = 0;
}
```

The problem is that the `NORVirtualPlayer` instances never get an initiated `pointRollers` property. I've stepped through everything and the setup method in the parentClass is called as are the subclass...

This feels like it must be a fairly basic problem but I'm just not able to wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

---

Solution: Like stated below. Embarrassing, but happy nevertheless. Kudos to Putz1103 for actually getting there first. I figured the super's setup would be called by its init-method but not so obviously...

Comment: Is your subclass `setup` function getting called twice?  It probably overloaded the parent class's `setup` function so that really doesn't exist anymore.  You could call `[super setup]` in your sublcass setup function.

Comment: @MrBr Yup, also `self.pointRollers = [tempRollersArray copy]` and _pointRollers = [tempRollersArray copy]` all to no avail.

Comment: @Putz1103 Nope, I've stepped through everything. The subclass' init executes the parents init which runs the parents setup. Then it runs the subclass' setup afterwards...

Comment: Have you checked the memory location of the array in the superclass and then check the memory location of the array in the subclass to see if they are the same pointer?

Comment: The problem is that the subclass never gets the array, it's always `nil`.

Comment: Putz is correct. When creating a NORVirtualPlayer object, the code above will call -[NORVirtualPlayer setup] twice and never call -[NORPlayer setup].

Comment: *blush* Yup, Putz1103 is right, my bad (obviously).

Comment: Ouch, first on scene and the answer goes to someone else...  I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @Putz1103 If you want to put up an answer about how THERE ARE NOW TRULY PRIVATE METHODS IN OBJECTIVE-C I'd be happy to mark it useful... :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see your NORPlayer's setup getting called from NORVirtualPlayer, which is where the array is initialized.

```
- (void)setup{
    self.minimumAcceptedValuePerRound = @[ @5, @5, @5, @5, @5 ];
    self.scoreGoal = 25;
    self.acceptedValueAdditionWhenScoreGoalReached = 0;
}
```

Did you want to call your super's setup too?

```
- (void)setup{
    [super setup];
    self.minimumAcceptedValuePerRound = @[ @5, @5, @5, @5, @5 ];
    self.scoreGoal = 25;
    self.acceptedValueAdditionWhenScoreGoalReached = 0;
}
```